# My Atom says: "bash: javac: command not found"

Tags: linux-mint, java

Atom  not finding JAVAC command.

Current Java version

```
openjdk version "11.0.3" 2019-04-16   OpenJDK Runtime Environment
(build 11.0.3+7-Ubuntu-1ubuntu218.04.1)   OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM
(build 11.0.3+7-Ubuntu-1ubuntu218.04.1, mixed mode, sharing)
```

```
echo $PATH
 /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin
```

Comment: What does `javac -version` output?

Comment: @StephenKitt "javac 11.0.3", im sorry

Comment: OK, so your Java environment appears to be correctly configured; this sounds more like an Atom problem, I’m not familiar with that.

Comment: @StephenKitt visual studio code can't find jdk either. But Eclipce can.

Comment: If this question actually explained that the problem was that although you can run these programs as commands from an interactive shell (some of) your IDEs fail to run them, it would be a lot clearer.

Comment: How was Java installed? Do you have `$JAVA_HOME` and related env vars?

Comment: Hehe, i dont have. But now... Nothing. doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your system, but maybe this will help

Do `which java`, and it should get you where the os is looking for it. Your PATH setting should be working.

Do `ls -al /bin/java`, and it might be a link to somewhere else. These links (again, depending on your OS version/distro) might get screwed up.

Follow the links and see if the end of the yellow brick road leads to somewhere, or invalid installation, perhaps?

Comment: "which java" says "/usr/bin/java"

Comment: usr/bin/java exists. it is just a file

Comment: It's `javac` that can't be found, not `java`.

Comment: usr/bin/javac exists too

Comment: Is that a link? What is your OS/version? and what is the response for `ls -al /usr/bin/javac`?